# I want to reset index but want to have all the columns in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
                          a       b           ...          c         d
DateTime                                      ...                       

2016-07-01 00:00:00  994.758209  31.556425    ...          NaN       NaN

2016-07-01 12:00:00  994.727417  29.273750    ...          NaN       NaN

2016-07-02 00:00:00  996.516484  26.598056    ...          NaN       NaN

2016-07-04 00:00:00  997.588235  10.686389    ...          NaN       NaN

2016-07-04 12:00:00  994.347107  25.472639    ...          NaN       NaN
```

my index is datetime but i want to set default index from `0,1...to n` but want to retain my datetime index as column in dataframe.

`reset_index()` drops the index and I'm not able to get the datetime as a column.

How can I do that?

Comment: `df = df.reset_index()` not working?

Comment: @jezrael it is working but as i told datetime is my index so it removes from the dataframe but i want to keep it as a column and add a normal index value like 0,1,,n

Comment: df['date'] = df.index and then reset the index.. ?

Comment: My bad i was putting inplace=true

Answer (score 2):

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', parse_dates=['DateTime'], index_col='DateTime')

                             a          b
           DateTime     
2016-07-01 00:00:00 994.758209  31.556425
2016-07-01 12:00:00 994.727417  29.273750
2016-07-02 00:00:00 996.516484  26.598056
2016-07-04 00:00:00 997.588235  10.686389
2016-07-04 12:00:00 994.347107  25.472639

df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 5 entries, 2016-07-01 00:00:00 to 2016-07-04 12:00:00
Data columns (total 2 columns):
a    5 non-null float64
b    5 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(2)

df = df.reset_index()

               DateTime          a          b
0   2016-07-01 00:00:00 994.758209  31.556425
1   2016-07-01 12:00:00 994.727417  29.273750
2   2016-07-02 00:00:00 996.516484  26.598056
3   2016-07-04 00:00:00 997.588235  10.686389
4   2016-07-04 12:00:00 994.347107  25.472639
```

`df.reset_index()` should not drop the `DateTime` column

If this doesn't resolve the issue, post your code in the original question.